# How to write multiple commands to BLE Device

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm working on an app which needs to get data from BLE device to show on app. In order to get datas from BLE device I have to write certain commands like `NUM_QUEUE`, `READ_ALL` etc.

So I'm stuck here to execute all commands together; I assigned all commands into an array and execute write function on loop by fetching each commands.

But when I read value I got the value of only last command in the array.

Here is the code:

```
 func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {

        if let characterArray = service.characteristics as [CBCharacteristic]? {
            for cc in characterArray {
                myCharacteristic = cc 
                peripheral.readValue(for: cc) 
                peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: myCharacteristic)
                writeValue()
            }
        }
    }
```

```
func writeValue() {

        if isMyPeripheralConected { //check if myPeripheral is connected to send data
            let arrayCommands = ["NUM_QUEUE\r","READ_ALL\r"]
            for i in 0...arrayCommands.count-1 {
                let dataToSend: Data = arrayCommands[i].data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
                myBluetoothPeripheral.writeValue(dataToSend, for: myCharacteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse)
            }
           
        } else {
            print("Not connected")
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Can you please post the code you are using?

Comment: added, please have a look

Answer (score 0):

I would use `enum` for keeping all of the commands together. Like so:

```
enum Command: String {

case NUM_QUEUE = "..."
case READ_ALL  = "..."
```

This way you can also get `rawValue` if you need it.

Comment: Swift convention is for enum cases to be in camel case `case numQueue, readAll`

Comment: @Daniel Thank you Daniel for telling that - I honestly didn't know. I just use caps in my project which is about working with BLE devices.

Comment: @Lilya When you used enum are you able to read all values from each commands

Comment: @iOS In my case each command has only one ```rawValue``` that I can read. And to reach it I use, for example,  ```Command.NUM_QUEUE```. I can also write only one command at a time to my BLE device. 
 I just figured that maybe using an enum would be better. Try to put your commands to the enum and iterate over it like so: https://www.simpleswiftguide.com/how-to-iterate-over-enum-cases-in-swift/

Answer (score 0):

Create an enum that has a `String` raw value type and follows the `CaseIterable` protocol. This allows you to enumerate your commands using `BluetoothCommand.allCases.forEach`

I've also simplified your code slightly by using an anonymous argument `$0` which in this case will correspond to each of your enum cases. I also shortened `String.Encoding.utf8` to just `.utf8` because I believe its type can be inferred by the compiler.

```
enum BluetoothCommand: String, CaseIterable {
    case numQueue = "NUM_QUEUE\r"
    case readAll = "READ_ALL\r"
}

func writeValue() {

    if isMyPeripheralConected { //check if myPeripheral is connected to send data
        BluetoothCommand.allCases.forEach {
            let dataToSend: Data = $0.rawValue.data(using: .utf8)!
            myBluetoothPeripheral.writeValue(dataToSend, for: myCharacteristic, type: .withResponse)
        }

    } else {
        print("Not connected")
    }

}
```